# Easy regex in gsub() function is not working

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have just started with programming in R. Currently, I am practicing feature engineering on the famous Titanic dataset.

Inter alia, I want to extract the title of the persons in my dataset.

I have these:

```
Montvila, Rev. Juozas 
Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen
```

And want to get these:

```
Rev.
Miss.
```

My own approach is not working. I cant figure out what exactly the problem is:

```
gsub("([A-Za-z:space:]+, )|(\.[A-Za-z:space:]+)", "", data_raw$Name)
```

Hope anybody can help me! Would be so great.

Kind regards,
Marcus

Comment: inside the brackets with other characters, you cannot put `:space:`, it will match the different characters (`:`, `s`, ...). Just put a space: `gsub("([A-Za-z ]+, )|(\\.[A-Za-z ]+)", "", "Montvila, Rev. Juozas")` gives you `"Rev"` (also to escape use double backslash, not simple, apart from that your regex was fine)

Comment: @Cath thank you! But why do I need to use double backslash instead of simple backslash? I've thought that we use `\` to escape the following character. And it is also described that way in stackoverflow's regex documentation..

Comment: it's just the way in R, to escape special characters, you do it with `\\` (for example `\\.` to escape a dot)

Comment: I would suggest to check this kaggle kernel (if you have a kaggle account): https://www.kaggle.com/mrisdal/titanic/exploring-survival-on-the-titanic You can simply use: `full$Title <- gsub('(.*, )|(\\..*)', '', full$Name)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a regex that will replace all text but the last chunk of letters followed with a dot.

```
> x <- c("Montvila, Rev. Juozas", "Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen")
> sub("^.*\\b([[:alpha:]]+\\.).*", "\\1", x)
[1] "Rev."  "Miss."
```

Or a simpler `regmatches` solution:

```
> unlist(regmatches(x, regexpr("[[:alpha:]]+\\.", x)))
[1] "Rev."  "Miss."
```

Or, if you need to check for a dot, but "exclude" it from the match, use a PCRE regex with `regmatches` (`perl=TRUE`) that allows using lookarounds in the pattern:

```
> unlist(regmatches(x, regexpr("[[:alpha:]]+(?=\\.)", x, perl=TRUE)))
[1] "Rev"  "Miss"
```

Here, `(?=\\.)` is a positive lookahead that requires a `.` after 1+ letters, but excludes it from the match.

**Details**:

- `^`  - start of a string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last...
- `\\b`  - word boundary
- `([[:alpha:]]+\\.)` - Group 1: one or more letters followed with a literal `.`
- `.*` - any 0+ chars up to the end of the string.

The TRE regex is used, so `.` matches any char including line break chars.

Also, in your code, the `.` is escaped with a single `\`, which results in an error since `\.` is a wrong escape sequence. Regex escapes must be defined with double backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for the regmatches solution. I haven't known this function before. Can you explain me why we put double [[ ]] around the :alpha:?

Comment: Yes, the `[:alpha:]` is a [POSIX character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posixbrackets.html), and cannot be used outside the bracket expression like `[....]`. Bracket expressions help use more than one POSIX character classes together to form a specific character type (e.g. `[[:alpha:][:punct:]1]` that will match 1 single character, either a letter, punctuation or a digit `1`)

Comment: Also note that I'd prefer the `regmatches` to `gsub` here since `gsub` will return the original string if no match is found, and `regmatches` will return no match.

Comment: Great, very helpful!

Comment: I have implemented the `regmatches` solution but I want to replace the `.` at the end of the title. But obviously, I can not just replace `\\.` at the end of the formula.

Comment: Use `> unlist(regmatches(x, regexpr("[[:alpha:]]+(?=\\.)", x, perl=TRUE)))` -> `[1] "Rev"  "Miss"`. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We can match one or more non white space characters (`\\S+`) from the start (`^`) of the string followed by one or more whitespace (`\\s+`) or (`|`) use a look around to match the `.` followed by characters until the end of the string and replace it with blank (`""`)

```
gsub("^\\S+\\s+|(?<=\\.).*$", "", str1, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "Rev."  "Miss."
```

---

Or another option is to capture the characters as a group (`([^.]+\\.)`) and in the replacement use the backreference (`\\1`) of that capture group.

```
sub("^[^,]+,\\s+([^.]+\\.).*", "\\1", str1)
#[1] "Rev."  "Miss."
```

#### data

```
str1 <- c("Montvila, Rev. Juozas", "Johnston, Miss. Catherine Helen")
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Especially, the second hint was very helpful since I haven't known that option before.

Comment: But one question concerning your first suggestion: Would that also work for a surname like "Test1 Test2, Mr. Test3"? Or would it be better than to use ([A-Za-z ]+, ) for the first part?

Comment: @ashbounty  The first case will not work for that because I used `\\S+\\s+` based on the pattern you showed while you have two words ("Test1" and "Test2")  followed by `,`

Comment: @ashbounty You can change the code to `gsub("^[^,]+,\\s*|(?<=\\.).*$", "", str1, perl = TRUE)#[1] "Rev."  "Miss." "Mr."`